# Splitting a string variable into parts

Tags: php

I have a variable which contains values like

```
1000*2/750
```

I want it to break into parts like

```
1000
2
750
```

So it can be stored in db in different columns.

Comment: You should show your efforts so far. Any code is appreciated. Tell us more about the format of the variable contents. Will it always be a*b/c?

Answer (score 1):

If you want find groups of digit, split string by non-digit sequence

```
$input= "1000*2/750";
$output = preg_split("/[\D+]/", $input);
print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to split the string with multiple delimiters, perhaps preg_split would be appropriate.

Try:

```
$input= "1000*2/750";
$output = preg_split("/(\*|\/)/", $input);
```

Using explode function:

```
function explodeX( $delimiters, $string )
{
    return explode( chr( 1 ), str_replace( $delimiters, chr( 1 ), $string ) );
}

$list =  "1000*2/750";

$exploded = explodeX( array('*', '/'), $list );

print_r($exploded);
```

Comment: Its  working fine .I was using explode but it accept only one parameter.I am new to php. Can i use explode in anyway?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $q="1000*2/750";
    $str=str_replace('/',' ',str_replace('*',' ',$q));
    $exp=explode(" ",$str);
    echo $exp[0];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $exp[1];
    echo "<br>";
    echo $exp[2];
```

this code will help you to do this..([str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php))

this result is also achieved by [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this coding.It definitely gonna works:

```
<?php

print_r(split("[/.*]", "1000*2/750"));

?>
```

Comment: Warning
This function was DEPRECATED in PHP 5.3.0, and REMOVED in PHP 7.0.0.

Answer (score 0):

```
$input= "1000*2/750";
$v = explode('-',str_replace(array('*','/'),'-',$input));
print_r($v);
```